# Microsoft word theme/document template

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working on my final year dissertation for university and the standard microsoft word theme/template for standard documents is not very appealing. Are there any sites or links you can give me to download any more professional and better looking themes/document templates. Im a mac user by the way if this makes any difference.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of office are you running? Here is a list of office templates.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT010152732.aspx

Comment: im running version 14 word 2011